# How can i get Json format data through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to get the value of count and year but unable to get. I have tried this so far.

```
[
    [{
        "count": 130,
        "year": "Week 1"
    }],[{
        "count": 160,
        "year": "Week 2"
    }],[{
        "count": 190,
        "year": "Week 3"
    }]
]
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
alert(parsedData.count);
alert(parsedData[0].count);
alert(parsedData[0].year);
```

Comment: Are you in control of the JSON? As you have a seemingly redundant nested array, and array of arrays containing a single object. You could massively simplify and improve that structure.

Comment: i tried this but it is giving this error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: When you are looking at objects remember each [] is a layer in an array. So first bracket [i], second bracket you hit [i][j], then you hit {} where you can now use object notation.

Answer (score 3):

`parseddata` is a 2 dimensional array. Try accessing the data like this.

```js
var data = '[[{"count":130,"year":"Week 1"}],[{"count":160,"year":"Week 2"}],[{"count":190,"year":"Week 3"}]]';

var parseddata = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(parseddata[0][0].count);
console.log(parseddata[0][0].year);
```

As **`@Rory McCrossan`** mentioned, your JSON is too messy. It can be simple as below.

```js
var data = [{
  "count": 130,
  "year": "Week 1"
}, {
  "count": 160,
  "year": "Week 2"
}, {
  "count": 190,
  "year": "Week 3"
}];

console.log(data[0].count);
console.log(data[0].year);
```

Comment: i make this json what you said but still unable to get data

Comment: At least the first snippet should work. What error are you getting ?